# Bootstrap 4 Image and text alignment

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have spent the entire day on this problem and queried and have not found the exact answer. I am not a Bootstrap 4 expert yet. I have the following page that I did.

```
<div class="card">
    <img src="~/img-theme/about-us-banner.png" class="img-fluid" />
    <div class="text-block opacity-4">
    </div>
    <h2 class="ontop">About Us</h2>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <p>text block here</p>
</div>
```

The custom CSS is:

```
    .text-block {
   position: relative;
   bottom: 300px;
   right: 20px;
   background-color: black;
   padding: 12rem;
   width: 30%;
   margin: auto;
   text-align:center;
   }


   h2.ontop {
   position: relative;
   top: -8em;
   font-size: 4rem;
   color: white;
   text-align:center;
   }
```

How do I get the text to appear below the image without the big white space?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to work with your **bottom: 300px;** value because it is causing a lot of space under your div.

```
.text-block {
   bottom: 300px;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

Html:

```
<div class="card">
    <img src="~/img-theme/about-us-banner.png" class="img-fluid" />
    <div class="text-block opacity-4">
        <h2 class="ontop">About Us</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.text-block {
position: relative;
background-color: black;
padding: 4rem;
width: 20%;
margin: auto;
text-align:center;
}


h2.ontop {
position: relative;
color: red;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.text-block {
   position: absolute;
   /* bottom: 300px; */
   /* right: 20px; */
   background-color: black;
   padding: 12rem;
   /* width: 30%; */
   margin: auto;
   text-align:center;
   align-self: center;
   top:200px
   
   }


   h2.ontop {
   position: relative;
   /* top: -8em; */
   font-size: 4rem;
   color: white;
   text-align:center;
   
   }
```

```html
   <div class="card">
                        <img src="order.png" class="img-fluid" />
                        <div class="text-block opacity-4">
                                     <h2 class="ontop">About Us</h2>
                        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>text block here</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

The above answers sort of worked, but did not respond well. Here is what I ended up doing:

```
    <div class="card card-block border-white">
    <img src="~/img-theme/about-us-banner.png" class="img-fluid" />
    <div class="text-block card-img-overlay opacity-4 d-none d-md-block">
    </div>
    <h2 class="ontop text-responsive">About Us</h2>
    </div>
```

And the CSS (I don't show the black box on XS screens anymore)

```
    .text-block {
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 6rem;
  width: 40%;
  height: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: -6rem;
  text-align:center;
}


h2.ontop {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 400%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align:center;
  bottom: 10rem;
}




@media (max-width: 1199px) {
h2.ontop {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 400%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align:center;
  bottom: 7.5rem;
}
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
h2.ontop {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 300%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align:center;
  bottom: 6rem;
}
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
h2.ontop {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 300%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align:center;
  bottom: 6rem;
}
}
```